# whenever i get an error in python console it exit the shell?

Tags: python, console

I have put up the code I am trying in a screen-shot. In short, **whenever I come across the particular error** the python shell **automatically exits**. I don't understand why.

The error is,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: substring not found.
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your output as text, not as an image.

Comment: Can you provide the crash log? Oh and Welcome to StackOverflow! please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking question properly will help you get better answers and help others be able to understand your question if they have a similar problem.

Comment: I'm wondering about the output `s:` and below. It is unexpected.

Comment: Are you sure python3 is the interactive python console? Can you check `alias python3`

Comment: can someone tell me what is this ?                                                                           why it prompts like this                                                                                                   s:      s:{}    t:{}